# An embedded Hazelcast member takes little more time to join back to the cluster after restarting

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, hazelcast

I'm trying to build a two node hazelcast  cluster with spring boot integration.

Configurations are as follows,

- Hazelcast port : 5900,
- Auto increment : true,
- Outbound port : 12000,
- Multicast enabled : false,
- tcp enabled : true,
- members :192.168.1.28,192.168.1.29,

Didn't changed any other properties.

Initially both will join on start, Once i restarted one of the nodes it takes almost 5-10 mins to join.

Is there any loop holes in my configuration? Why it is not joining instantly on startup.?

Comment: If you have a `hazelcast.xml` can you post the `<network>...</network>` part of it please ? Logs will be useful too if possible

Comment: The configuration shouldn't cause a join delay, the node will either find each other and join immediately, or not find each other and never join. Potentially the restarting node is waiting for the port to be fully released by the previous process ; logs will help

Comment: I'm configuring in java, spring bean configuration. As i mentioned nothing else than above defined properties changed.

Comment: @NeilStevenson, as you mentioned  "Potentially the restarting node is waiting for the port to be fully released by the previous process" i also thought about this.Now fortunately it is working with two extra properties :   
_port_  _auto_ _increment_ = false,  
_port_ _count_ = 1.  
Instance(Member) restarted is stopped polling its neighbours, it only tries to connect specified `IP:PORT` and connecting/joining instantly.
Thanks for your precious time and reply  @NeilStevenson. I will inform if anything unfortunate happened again.

Comment: So it's working ?  Port count is only used when _auto-increment==true_, so you don't need to bother with this ; it determines an upper bound on the incrementing.

Comment: @SudarshanNavada Have you managed to achieve the desired behavior ? because I am facing exact same issue with exact same spring java based configuration. If you succeed, please tell me what is it that takes time to re-join the cluster for new instance ?

Comment: Now instances are immediately joining once they are up. 

I don't have that old logs, also i don't know what exactly was happened. But i remember that
1) When we give out bound port in some range, the instances were trying to connect to multiple outbound ports of another instance one after another and they are added to blacklist.
2) In the configuration i specified above i.e. in question, i restricted to use only one outbound port 12000 in each of 3 instances, that will not work. Because at least n-1 ports should be given to outbound ports. Where `n` is number of instances in the cluster.

Comment: Now i changed the configurations to 

`hazelcast-instance.instance-name=hazelcast`,
`hazelcast-instance.group=dev`,
`hazelcast-instance.port=5900`,
`hazelcast-instance.members=192.168.1.28,192.168.1.29,192.168.1.30`,
`hazelcast-instance.outboundport=12000,12001`,
`hazelcast-instance.port-auto-increment=false`, Hope this configuration will help.